# Command pattern - How to preserve execution state?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, domain-driven-design, cqrs, command-pattern

I have the folowing opertaion. I need to create a reservation, during the create of reservation I need to orchestrate several things. The reservation is ordered through a third party system, then an e-mail is sent , then a price offer is finalized and so on...

Can I encapuslate this logic in a single CreateReservationCommand or I need to have three commands and then what pattern would orchestrate the command execution ?  Can a command has execution state at all ?

Also I have the feeling that the Command in the sense of gang of four is different than the Command in the sense of CQRS for example. Am I right ?

UPDATE:

What makes me confused here is that in terms of CQRS you can have a commands and events and lets supposed that third party system sends a message to my system CREATE_RESERVATION wouldn't this in the context of CQRS be a command and yet this is more of a complete workflow probably SAGA pattern ?

Comment: Command is a transaction - it is either completed or failed. There is no third state. What you are describing looks like saga / process manager to me

Comment: You need a Saga. You can read this answer about how to initialize a Saga: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/381727/cross-aggregate-operations-use-domain-service-or-domain-events/381755#381755

Answer (score 3):

> Can I encapuslate this logic in a single CreateReservationCommand or I need to have three commands and then what pattern would orchestrate the command execution ? Can a command has execution state at all ?

You can... but usually the book keeping of orchestration uses something like the [process manager pattern](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ProcessManager.html), which would span multiple transactions.

> I have the feeling that the Command in the sense of gang of four is different than the Command in the sense of CQRS for example. Am I right ?

You are absolutely correct -- completely different ideas.  "Command in CQRS" is a descendant of Gregor Hohpe's [Command Message](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/CommandMessage.html) pattern.